# customize Id generated by heat

Tags: wix, heat

I'm new to wix toolset, and I want to know if there's a way to customize Id generated by heat from random ID to

```
Fil.path.to.file.xx
```

Answer (score 0):

For something that specific you'd have to write an XSLT.  That's so complicated that you might just want to write your own wxs generator.